# Volume too low using hdmi from mac air

Tags: hdmi

I tried connecting my Mac-Air to my TV using the HDMI adapter. The volume is very low. Even cranked all the way up, it is still not loud enough watching hulu, netflix etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the TV volume all the way up? Is the MBAir volume all the way up? Or both?

Comment: Yep. Both turned all the way up.

Comment: Oh, and what adapter are you using? Given that a MBAir doesn't have an HDMI jack.

Comment: Apple's display port -> HDMI adapter

Comment: no, this is a problem even when output is directed to the the HDMI cable. needs a separate audio cable from the headphone jack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you select the correct HDMI Output in System Preferences | Sound. You are probably still listening to the sound through the mac speakers.

*sheepish*